# Finding the geometric mean of points on a globe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, math, maps, geometry

I'm starting a project where I am mapping a set of points on the Earth using google maps. I want to find the point on the globe which is the average (shortest total distance to all points), but I'm unsure how to handle it considering the distance may be shorter going the other way around the earth. (-178 degrees to 178 degrees longitude is only 4 degrees longitude apart, not 356). What is the best way to approach this, either via an api call or from a mathematical perspective?

Comment: Neither "average" nor "shortest distance to all points" is well-defined.  Do you want to minimax (minimize the maximum distance between the point and points in the original set)?  Do you want to minimize the average distance between the point and the points in the original set?

Comment: I would like to minimize the average distance between the point and the original points in the set.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest simple and fast solution (but not to exact initial task). Find the [center of gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_gravity) of points, then there may be 2 situations:

1. it's located at center of sphere - don't know what to do (if initial points distributed close to each other - this will not happen)
2. in other case - consider vector with center of mass and center of sphere as finish and start points, find where such vector intersects surface of sphere, that point - is the answer.

So, you'll get point somewhat similar to 'mid-point', but only in cases when surface under consideration is very small (may be all point lay within the same city). But it is also has nothing to do with minimal average distances from result to initial points.

Comment: This is false.  Consider three points: the North Pole together with the two points on the Prime Meridian *just* epsilon south of the 60th parallel south.  Their center of mass is *just* south of the Earth's core, so your algorithm would prescribe the South Pole.  However the average distance from the South Pole to these three points is *just* under `5*PI*r/9` (where `r` is the Earth's radius) whereas if we had chosen the North Pole, we'd get an average distance *just* above `4*PI*r/9`.

Comment: Yes, I agree, there may be not suitable results. But if points lay considerably near to each other you'll get somewhat practically acceptable result... But again, suggested algo has nothing to do with any kind of shortest distance on surface.

Comment: Actually, that's not true either, which suggests an even simpler counterexample.  Consider 3 points on the Prime Meridian, at latitudes of 0, 0.5, and 10 (in degrees).  Then the point which gives the smallest average distance is the point with latitude 0.5 itself.  Your algorithm recommends the point at latitude 3.496526579822483....  The average distance for your point is 29.96526579822483...% greater than the optimal average distance given.  30% off is pretty egregious.

Comment: Ok, sorry! It's solution not to initial task, but I already mentioned that.
Regarding your numerical solution (if you want to fight with numbers, I'll try too):
Meridian arc length measuring 20003.93km (as from wikipedia). So if I want to find midpoint with precision of 1m, I'll need to assign `precision` to ~0.0000001 in your algo, and because its complexity O(steps^2) it'll do ~10^15 ops. It's too large number, you see (not speaking Ruby itself not so suitable for math calculations). So, you should suggest more efficient algo, may be based on Nelder-Mead method or dichotomy.

Comment: Would have been my answer as this is a natural extension of the circular mean http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities

Comment: Why would anyone care about being correct to 1m?  You care about how close the value of the objective function at your point is to the optimal value, not how close your point is to the optimal point.

Comment: Also, if you want to obtain such a fine precision, you obviously shouldn't run the algorithm with 0.00000001, you should run the algorithm with, say, 0.005, grab the result (say coordinates are (x,y)), re-run the algorithm to only let latitude vary from x-0.005 to x+0.005 and similar for longitude with precision = 0.0000025, and repeat this process until you've reached desired precision.  This will be about 10^7 calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt there is a slick geometric argument giving a closed form expression for the desired point.  Nonetheless here's a simple-minded algorithm which gives an answer to within any desired precision:

https://gist.github.com/amitkgupta/5019163

If you want a mathematically more satisfying solution, I recommend asking over at http://math.stackexchange.com, or they don't avail you, escalate it to http://mathoverflow.net.